# Assigning key/value names to perl hash and iterating

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash that is populated by hundreds of lines of data always in this format. Essentially i want the first element to be the key and all the other elements in the row to be values. How do I assign key/value names to these elements and print certain elements?

```
810804 20140320          spores    -         20140324          spores     8.0.5    -          WONT_FIX   3 - HW           -                  0       fast        -                 |its broken!
801001 20140214          nagaraju   PANIC     20140220          geetha      6.0      -          NEW        5 D SW_OCUM      -                  0       fast        -                 |  dead
```

What I have here will essentially get the data, create the hash and print everything.

```
#!/usr/software/bin/perl
use strict;
my $command = `very_long_cli_cmd`;
my %burtinfo = $command;
print "$_ $burtinfo{$_}\n" for (keys %burtinfo);
```

How do I add names to these elements and print specific things? I was trying something like this, but it just overwrites my existing hash:

```
 my %burthash = (
        "id"                 => "",
        "date_create"        => "",
        "sub_by"           => "",
        "impact"           => "",
        "date-lastmod"     => "",
        "lastmod_by"       => "",
        "bug_rel"          => "",
        "case_score"       => "",
        "state"            => "",
        "s"                => "",
        "p"                => "",
        "tye"              => "",
        "subtype"          => "",
        "subteam"          => "",
        "found_by"         => "",
        "target_release"   => "",
        "title"            => "",
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @cols = qw/date_create sub_by impact/;  #etc. Removed id, because the 
                                          #key for the entry is the id
my @burtInfo = `cli command`;
my %burtHash;
while(my $ele = shift(@burtInfo)){
    my ($index, @data) = split(/\s+/, $ele);
    for my $i(0 .. $#cols){
        $burtHash{$index}->{$cols[$i]} = shift(@data);
    }
}
```

The above makes the below example data structure. Note %burthash is a hash of hashes.

```
$VAR1 = '801001';
$VAR2 = {
          'date_create' => '20140214',
          'impact' => 'PANIC',
          'sub_by' => 'nagaraju'
        };
$VAR3 = '810804';
$VAR4 = {
          'date_create' => '20140320',
          'impact' => '-',
          'sub_by' => 'spores'
        };
```

We can't tell you why you are overwriting the `%burtHash` without the related code being in your question.

Here is an example of printing all of the dates.

```
for my $key(keys %burtHash){
    print $burtHash{$key}->{'date_create'}, "\n"; #notice, we got the id from the key,
                                           #and use that to access that ids info.
}
```

The Above prints:

```
20140214
20140320
```

Printing only the keys

```
print "$_\n" for(keys %burtHash);
```

Output:

```
801001
810804
```

Comment: I tried this in the while loop, but it just prints "Test:" for every line in the hash `code`print "Test:  " . $burtHash{'id'} . "\n";`code`

Comment: O, I see, try putting \t instead of \s+ in the split.

Comment: @quantumspores, there is no `$burtHash{'id'}`. try using one of the index values like `$burtHash{'810804'}->{'id'}`. that said, you should remove id from this script, because the key is the id

Comment: i have no way of knowing what the id value is (except in this example)

Comment: @quantumspores of course you don't, we don't usually know either. That is why you use a [for loop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#For-Loops)

Comment: so i'm still unsure of how to print values ... since I don't know 810804 exists?

Comment: @quantumspores add the examples I put in my answer to your script.

Comment: I tried several different value ID's but just prints blank spaces.

Comment: did you try the examples I put in?

Comment: I did. The problem seems to have something to do with the split. When I try other regex I get some results (although none correct)

Comment: You have to put all the column names into @cols, and you have to do it in the order you expect to get the data.

Comment: Yeah, i;ll figure out why the split isn't doing exactly what it should - I appreciate the help.

Comment: I just tested with \s+ on the input you provided and it worked perfectly fine for me. Be sure to compare any changes to the original script I provided to the one you have.

Comment: @quantumspores added the output of this script.

Comment: the problem turns out to be that some values may be strings (multiple words with whitespaces). thanks!